# Highlight link if in directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a series of links which currently remain highlighted if on the  current url (using query and css).

My question is, what if I want it to remain highlighted not because of the page but if still within that directory? ie. If I click multi links on the page that is still within that directory for that particular link to remain highlighted. Hope that makes sense.

Jquery:

```
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $('.section li a').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

css

```
.section li a.current {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to do this solely with jQuery and css (no backend), you'll probably need to add your <script> to each page that you want that link to remain highlighted on.

Answer (score 0):

you can read URL if it contains the name of the directory

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("SOMETHING") > -1) {
// HIGHLIGHT
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the "current" class to the parent directory as well. This way, both the line and the parent directory is highlighted.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.section li a').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('current');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```